# Using a li-ion battery instead of an AC adapter

Tags: power-supply, batteries, lithium-ion, adapter, laptop

I have a board that uses a 19v 3.42A AC adapter as a power supply and I want to replace that with a Li-ion battery. What should the voltage of the battery be? I ask this because my laptop for example uses a 14.4v battery while having a 19v 6.32A AC adapter.

Comment: Batteries don't have a consistent voltage during discharge, so you'd need to know the actual requirements of the device in terms of allowable voltage range.  Given the the fairly high current draw, overall this sounds like a fairly bad idea.  And anyway, both questions on the *usage* of devices and questions seeking *purchase* recommendations are off topic here.  To be on topic, you'd need to present meaningful specifications in terms of both the boundaries of allowed voltage, and the expected *actual* rate of power consumption.

Comment: And keep in mind that your laptop doesn't expect the battery to substitute for the supply, but handles it specifically in being *designed* to use that particular battery - a design which includes unique connections to the battery pack distinct from those of the power supply.

Comment: This is the only information I currently have, I did ask the supplier for more details regarding power consumption and I am waiting for a reply. And with regards to the high current draw, I would only need to use it for about 45min ~ 60min each time, so I think a 5000mAh battery would suffice.

Comment: You’d be better off keeping the existing AC adapter, and using a rechargeable 12V battery (gel cell) and AC inverter to supply mains voltage to the adapter. Easily available, inexpensive, safer, and useful for other devices.